# Printing the result of a map object in python that is not convertible to list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I was attempting to try out map function and end up with the following:

```
x=[1,2,-3,4]
result=(map(sum,x))
print(list(result))
```

Result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-5270e85794e8> in <module>
      1 result=(map(sum,x))
----> 2 print(list(result))

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I understand the reason for the error above but please help me with how to print the result.

Comment: Your code calls `sum()` on each number in the list individually. What `result` are you hoping for?

Comment: Why do you want to use `map()` at all?  Why not just `result = sum(x)`?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, i misunderstood maps and was hoping that it would result in sum of the entire list. But now that i understood , why is the answer which is sum of each value which should result in  the value itself throwing a syntax error when trying to convert to list?

Comment: sum function operates on a list of numbers, by passing it as parameter to map you request it to be called on every number individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map does a delayed execution, so when you cast the result to a list, the map is executed, which amounts in computing `sum(1)`, `sum(2)`, `sum(-3)` and `sum(4)`

Any of those will fail because sum takes something like a list (an iterable object) in input. You pass integers which are not iterable, hence the error message.

As suggested in the comments, you want to do a simple `sum(x)`.

Comment: Agree. I should have said any of those would fail, and when the first fails, an exception is thrown and nothing further happens. Fixed in the text.